# lambda calculus for functional programming

Tags: functional-programming, lambda, lambda-calculus

in lambda calculus (λ x. λ y. λ s. λ z. x s (y s z)) is used for addition of two Church numerals how can we explain this, is there any good resource the lambda calculus for functional programming ? your help is much appreciated

Comment: Check the "Related" section at the right side of the page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515413/what-are-some-resources-for-learning-lambda-calculus, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051033/lambda-calculus-and-church-numerals-confusion, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually λ f1. λ f2. λ s. λ z. (f1 s (f2 s z)) computes addition because it is in effect substituting (f2 s z), the number represented by f2, to the "zero" inside (f1 s z).

Example: Let's take two for f2, `s s z` in expanded form. f1 is one: `s z`. Replace that last `z` by f2 and you get `s s s z`, the expanded form for three.

This would be easier with a blackboard and hand-waving, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In lambda calculus, you code a datatype in terms of the operations it induces. For instance, a boolean is a just a choice function that takes in input two values a and b and either returns a or b:

```
                      true = \a,b.a   false = \a,b.b
```

What is the use of a natural number? Its main computational purpose is to
provide a bound to iteration. So, we code a natural number as an operator
that takes in input a function f, a value x, and iterate the application
of f over x for n times:

```
                        n = \f,x.f(f(....(f x)...))
```

with n occurrences of f.

Now, if you want to iterate n + m times the function f starting from x
you must start iterating n times, that is (n f x), and then iterate for m
additional times, starting from the previous result, that is

```
                                m f (n f x)
```

Similarly, if you want to iterate n*m times you need to iterate m times
the operation of iterating n times f (like in two nested loops), that is

```
                                 m (n f) x
```

The previous encoding of datatypes is more formally explained in terms
of constructors and corresponding eliminators (the so called
Bohm-Berarducci encoding).